# Duplicated Citation using BibTex / TexStudio

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing, apa-style

I am new to LateX and I am currently having problems with citations and references.  So, I have my References.bib files which contains all the elements of my bibliogaphy, and then I have the file Chapter_I.tex which contains the real content of my document.

When i need to cite something, I use the command \cite{KEY01} in-text, but when I build the file, the name and the year of the referenced document appear twice, like:

(Author, 2017; uthor, 2017)

This happens to every single reference I have in my text (by the way, I chose the APA style for referencing).
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong and how could I possibly fix it?
Thanks

Here's some code if you need it

***This is a generic entry of my Reference.bib file:

```
@online{WSJ01,
      author    =   "Barnes, Julian, E. and Chin, Josh",
      year      =   2018,
      month     =   "march",
      day       =   "2",
      title     =   "The New Arms Race in AI",
      url       =   {\url{https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-new-arms-race-in-ai-1520009261}},
 }
```

***This is part of my Chapter_I.tex file:

```
    % !TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[
        pdfa,
        cucitura
        corpo=11pt,
        twoside,
        stile=classica,
        oldstyle,
        autoretitolo,
        tipotesi=magistrale,
        english,
        evenboxes,
]{toptesi}

\usepackage[
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen,
    pdfstartview=FitH,
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,
    urlcolor=blue
]{hyperref}

\usepackage[Latin1]{inputenc}
\input{commands}

\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
The United States recognized the implication of researching about AI, especially in defense systems. In its budget for AI, the Pentagon spent almost \$7,4 billion, an increase of 32\% from the 5,6 B\$ spent in 2012. However, the public sector is struggling in establishing partnerships with the private sector because of concerns about how AI could be deployed to harm people \cite{WSJ01}.


\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: An error that happens to every single reference, suggests that there is a mistake in the style file.  Are you using a standard style file, or have you customized it?

Comment: @Thruston if you refer to the bibliography style, then I am using the standard one named "apalike"

Comment: The apalike style is incompatible with apacite. Use the style apacite.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so, i changed `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` with 
`\bibliographystyle{apacite}`; however, it doesn't seem to work anyway.